# Entities in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

So basically I am making a Jail Management System. The first part is where an inmate is booked and that session has 5 screens namely:

Booking Screen 1
Booking Screen 2
Booking Screen 3
Medical 
Property
Commissary

I have created entities and forms for all of them. I want the functionality where i can move from the first booking screen to the rest by using like a "Next" button like we usually have in online forms over the internet. Can i achieve this?
or is there some way where I don't have to go to every entity and create a New record manually?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number of fields you could use 5 tabs instead of pages. The last field of every tab could hold a javascript that opens the next tab and close the previous tab.

Comment: by tabs you mean sections of a form?

Comment: ok so i can use Javascript to hide and show sections/tab.

lets say i have three sections in a form and i want only the first to show when i open the form and when i complete it i want to show the second and so on. how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a Dialog which will pass the values to Custom workflow activity(Written in c#). I have recently created a dialog for user registration.

Have a look at these link:

[Link 2](http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/02/04/utilising-dialogs-in-crm-2011-for-record-creation/)

[Link 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/02/02/welcome-to-the-world-of-dialogs-part-1.aspx)

[Link 3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309745.aspx)

[Link 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509010.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Scorpion suggestion, you can use dialog if all of input fields were in the same entity. If you want to use the Wizard to collection fields which were held in different entities. Then you can make a custom web page(e.g. ASP.NET) to handle it.

Comment: Hey Jeff what do you mean by if all the input fields are in the same entity?

Comment: from "all the input fields" he means that the values you are going to insert belongs to same Entity.